# How do I blend a promise with an observable?

Tags: rxjs, angular8, rxjs6

I'm having trouble promises and observables.  I have a handful of http requests which are defined in a package using promises.  In the rest of my code I am using observables for various things, including other http calls.  In one particular section I am checking to see if the user's bearer token is expired and if so then I get a new token and then proceed with the rest of the call.

```
if (!token || token.exp < Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000)) {
  from(this._store.refreshBearerToken())
    .pipe(flatMap(resp => {
       let newToken = resp.data;
       newToken.exp = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000 + newToken.expires_in;
       localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(newToken))

       options = options || {};
       options.headers = new HttpHeaders({
         "Authorization": `${newToken.token_type} ${newToken.access_token}`,
         "Content-Type": "application/json"
        });
       return this._http$.request<T>(method, url, options as Object).pipe(share());
     }));
}
```

Bearer Token method:

```
async refreshBearerToken() {
    const response = await this._q2.sources.requestExtensionData({
        route: "refreshBearerToken"
    });
    console.log(response);
    return response;
}
```

Since `this._store.refreshBearerToken` returns a promise I wrapped the call in a `from` to convert it to an observable.  This compiles but when it runs I get "Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined".

How can I convert this promise to an observable so that I can refresh the token and then continue with the rest of the call?

Edit:

I am importing `from` via `import { Observable, from } from "rxjs";`.

So, I thought the error was coming from the line `.pipe(flatMap(resp =>...` but I was wrong.  The error is coming from the method which is calling this.

```
GetInitialLinkList(): Observable<Institution[]>
{
    let base = { 'MemberId': localStorage.getItem('memberId') };
    let ins = localStorage.getItem("initialInstitutionList");
    if (ins)
    {
        return of(JSON.parse(ins));
    }
    return this._settingsService.get().pipe(
        flatMap(settings =>
        {
            this._settings = settings;
            return this._api.request<Institution[]>("Post", `${this._settings.mea}/GetInitialLinkList`, { body: base })
                .pipe(
                    retry(1),
                    catchError(this.handleError)
                )
                .pipe(flatMap(instList =>
                {
                    localStorage.setItem("initialInstitutionList", JSON.stringify(instList));
                    return of(instList);
                }))
        }));
}
```

and that is being subscribed to inside my component:

```
private GetLinkList()
{
    this.showWaiting.emit(true);
    this._data.GetInitialLinkList().subscribe((result) =>
    {
        this.initialList = result;
        this.showWaiting.emit(false);
    });
}
```

From what Brandon said (I forgot to return /facepalm...) I added the return so I have `return from(this._store.refreshBearerToken())` which changed my error to

```
ERROR Error Code: undefined
Message: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6014
```

Comment: What line throws the error? `from` returns an Observable.

Comment: @martin I added some details

Comment: FYI you should use `tap(x => sideEffect())` for side effects instead of `flatMap(x => { sideEffect(); return of(x); })`

Comment: Thanks @Brandon, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Otherwise, you are still not showing a complete code example.  What is `handleError`?  Where is your original code actually called?  All your original code is, is a code fragment.  Where's the rest of the method?  It is all guessing without seeing all of the methods involved in the call chain.

Comment: Sorry, trying to have a "minimal" code sample.  I actually think I have it working now.  Adding the `return` was huge of course and I think I found one other issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show the actual error and the line in the code that the error occurs on?  Also show where and how you import `from`.

I notice your code snippet does not return the observable it builds up via `from(...).pipe(...)` nor does it subscribe to it.  It might help to show how your code actually uses this observable.

Comment: /facepalm   Thanks, I added the return but I'm still getting errors.

Comment: My code still needs some work but the main part was that I was missing a `return`.  My `handleError` has issues but that is a different problem.  Thanks for your help on this.